# High-end CD/DVD burners?

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, burning, optical-drive, compact-disc

Do such things exist?  I wouldn't mind paying $100 to $200 for one, but it must:

1. Have a very fast spin-up to ready time (less than one second)
2. Have an even faster dismount time (say, half second)
3. Can go from dead stop to laying down bits in two seconds or less
4. Can be instantly abortable and resettable regardless of current operational state

Does anyone know of such an animal?

Comment: Could you give an example of a scenario in which you would need something like that ?

Comment: I just hate the el-cheapo ones. Any ordinary working scenario with a burner that had these characteristics would be more comfortable to use.

Comment: Sounds to me like what you're really after is a CD-Writer with USB flash disk type performance.  You could just buy a bucket load of 1GiB memory sticks dirt cheap from eBay...

Answer (score 4):

## No.

Under a second spin up times? No. Half second dismount times? No. Dead stop to burning in under two seconds? No. Instant abort? Pull the power plug and eject with a paper clip.

The features you have listed are past the point of physical limitations. If you spin the disc too fast it can shatter. If you put that much stress into a motor it can overheat and cause other problems. There are seek and access times along with mandatory data correction when burning that cannot be bypassed no matter how much it costs.

Answer (score 2):

Never seen one!

There are some which are better than others - I have been impressed with Asus for being very quiet, however, I have never seen anything that comes close to the specification you stated.

... Even CD Emulators are only close to most of those points!